# Why isn't my jQuery looped animation working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, loops, jquery-animate

I am trying to loop a jQuery animation along with the jQuery UI 'explode' effect infinitely until an event stops it. Here is my code:

```
function movingPicture() {
    $('img').delay(2800).animate({right: '44%'}, 3000, movingPicture).effect('explode');
    $('img').css('right', '-100px');
    $('img').show();
};
movingPicture();
```

This is supposed to have it loop infinitely according to some research I have done. An img would move left into view onto the document, explode, and then be reset back to the original position. Then, I would like it to perform the same animation infinitely until stopped. What am I doing wrong? Also, what is a way I could stop the loop when an event occurs, like a button is clicked. I am a beginner by the way, so try to keep it as simple as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do that like so

```
function movingPicture() {
    $('img').delay(2800).animate({right: '44%'}, 3000, function() {
        $(this).effect('explode', function() {
            $(this).css('right', '-100px').show();
            movingPicture();
        });
    });
}
movingPicture();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VD9Be/)